# would have been adj. had?

Tags: grammar

> The massive influx of women cyclists-making up at least a third of the total market- was perhaps the most striking and profound social consequence of the mid-1890s cycling boom. Although the new, improved bicycle had appealed immediately to a few privileged women, **its impact would have been modest had it not attracted a greater cross section of the female population**. It soon became apparent that many of these pioneer women bicyclists had not taken up the sport as an idle pastime. Rather, they saw cycling as a noble cause to be promoted among all women as a means to improve the general female condition. Not only would cycling encourage healthy outdoor exercise, they reasoned, it would also hasten long-overdue dress reform. To feminists, the bicycle affirmed nothing less than the dignity and equality of women.

There is a sentence

> ... its impact would have been modest had it not ...

I can't understand what grammar of "would have been adj. had" is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction *its impact would have been modest had it not attracted a greater cross section of the female population* is an example of a "*reduced conditional*". In this case it is the reduced, and more formal, version of the so-called *third conditional*:

> Its impact would have been modest if it had not attracted a greater
>   cross section of the female population.

The reduced conditional is often found with the protasis (the *if-clause*) first:

> Had it not attracted a greater cross section of the female population,
>   its impact would have been modest.

There is a brief section on *reduced conditionals* on the BBC webpage dealing with [inversion](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-26/session-1). Here is one of its examples:

> Had I stayed longer, I would have learned a new language.

Answer (score 0):

> ... its impact would have been modest *had it not attracted a greater*
>   *cross section of the female population*.

Normally the protasis of a conditional has the form of a PP with *if* as head and a content clause as complement.

But with remote conditionals with "has" (and "were") it is sometimes possible for it to take the form of an ungoverned content clause with subject-auxiliary inversion.

It’s the equivalent to *if it had not attracted a greater* ...